Skip Custom JWT Filter for /api/auth/signin while Using permitAll()
I'm using Spring Security 6 with a custom JwtAuthenticationFilter to handle JWT-based authentication for my API. However, despite using .permitAll() for the /api/auth/signin endpoint, the custom JwtAuthenticationFilter is still being executed for that endpoint, which is incorrect since no JWT should be required for the signin process.
Security Configuration:
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;

    public SecurityConfig(JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter) {
        this.jwtAuthenticationFilter = jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Configure CORS support
        http.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/api/auth/signin").permitAll()  // Allow signin endpoint
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/api/auth/signin").permitAll()  // Allow OPTIONS for /api/auth/signin
            .anyRequest().authenticated()  // Secure other requests
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class); // Register the custom JWT filter

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        // CORS configuration
        CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfig.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000"));  // Set your frontend domain here
        corsConfig.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));  // Allow these methods
        corsConfig.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Content-Type", "Authorization"));  // Allow these headers
        corsConfig.setAllowCredentials(true);  // Allow credentials like cookies, if needed

        // Register the CORS configuration
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfig);
        return source;
    }
}

Custom JwtAuthenticationFilter Implementation:
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    public JwtAuthenticationFilter(JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider) {
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        // Extract and validate JWT
        String jwt = getJwtFromRequest(request);
        
        if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {
            String username = jwtTokenProvider.getUsernameFromToken(jwt);

            // Set authentication in security context
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(jwtTokenProvider.getAuthentication(username));
        }

        // Continue with the filter chain
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String getJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7);  // Extract the token without the "Bearer " prefix
        }
        return null;
    }
}

Any idea?

Ofcourse the filter will be invoked. permitAll doesn't mean skip filters, it means everyone can access it. If this is your filter it should just continue, what you might need is anonymous() to at least have a SecurityContext available.

You have no condition for the filter to be skipped. There are two options:

Define conditional logic inside the doFilterInternal() method itself. With this approach, you must manually control the flow by calling filterChain.doFilter() inside the if block and using a return statement to skip your filter's main logic. And return is the main part here.

public void doFilterInternal(HttpServlerRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
  if (!request.getRequestURI().contains("/signin") {

    // proceed to other filters from filter chain
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

    // return from this method and filter respectively
    return;
  }
  // the rest of the filter's logic is omitted
}


Since you're extending OncePerRequestFilter, you can override the shouldNotFilter() method, which is designed to declare a condition and keep such logic centralized. If the condition is met (i.e., the method returns true), the filter will be skipped. Otherwise, the filter logic will be invoked.

@Override
protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
  return request.getRequestURI().contains("/signin");
}

